# How can I use the Raspberry Pi to connect a wired ethernet device to a wireless network

Tags: pi-3, wireless-adapter

I have a device I would like to connect to a wireless network but it does not have a wireless adapter.  The device does not have a console or monitor output so I can not log into the device.  I need to use the Raspberry Pi to log into the wireless network and then connect my device to the ethernet port on the Raspberry Pi.  Does anyone know how to do this?

**Update** with info from comment:
The device is a "Sharkrf open spot". It is used in ameatur radio to connect a radio in the ameatur band to the internet. It has an rf port for the ameatur radio input, but only a wired ethernet port pointing to the internet. I can log into the sharkrf once it is connencted to the internet. I can not directly access the sharkrf to before it is connected to the internet. So I need something for when I am traveling that will be able to log into a motel network that is password protected and then allow the sharkrf to connect to it.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B. I have it programed now as a wireless router with the wired ethernet connecting to a wired switch and the wireless side accepting connections. However, I need to switch the ports. I need the wireless side to connect to a a wireless network and be able to connect wired device (sharkrf open spot) to the wired ethernet port. This port must also act as a router and provide dhcp services. I have the PI working, I just need to reverse the ports. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Mr. John Moesner. Your question is ambiguous, Because at least I could not get what the "Device" is.
Please, tell some (more) detail about the "device".

Comment: The device is a "Sharkrf open spot".  It is used in ameatur radio to connect a radio in the ameatur band to the internet.  It has an rf port for the ameatur radio input, but only a wired ethernet port pointing to the internet.  I can log into the sharkrf once it is connencted to the internet.  I can not directly access the sharkrf to before it is connected to the internet.  So I need something for when I am traveling that will be able to log into a motel network that is password protected and then allow the sharkrf to connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have solved your problem after 2 years without an accepted answer but here is a solution for someone coming to this by google.

The problem is that you need to bridge the wired interface **eth0** with the client **wlan0** uplink to the internet router but this isn't supported by the on-board WiFi device of a Raspberry Pi 3B. So you have to use **routing** or **proxy arp**. How to do it with a single device like your "Sharkrf open spot" you can look at [eth0(single device) + wlan0(up-link)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98017/79866). There you will find a section "Use routing" and "Use proxy arp".

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need a WIFI dongle for the PI, simply because I believe the PI has only a single network card. Although you can connect the PI Wired *OR* wireless, you cant connect it to both at the same time without additional hardware. A small USB wireless dongle is very cheap these days, and using that you will be able to connect the "device" to your PI via the wired connection, and then the PI to the network via the WIFI dongle...

Best of luck with that... I can try this here, if you'll be needing the settings... let me know

Comment: I have mine connected to wifi and wired all the time. I'm not sure what you're talking about here.

Comment: I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B.  I have it programed now as a wireless router with the wired ethernet connecting to a wired switch and the wireless side accepting connections.  However, I need to switch the ports.  I need the wireless side to connect to a a wireless network and be able to connect wired device (sharkrf open spot) to the wired ethernet port.  This port must also act as a router and provide dhcp services.  I have the PI working, I just need to reverse the ports.  I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @JohnMoesner You mean something like this: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/ The key search term you need for more details are "_wifi to bridge_".