# Advice on how to use a RPi to connect Smart TV to the internet via wireless

Tags: ethernet, wireless

I have a Smart TV that has ethernet but no wireless capabilities.

I also have a spare RPi1 (Model B) with a wireless USB adapter.

Is there anyway I can use the Pi to connect the TV to my wireless router?

Answer (score 1):

i wished to comment only,

you are asking about bridging the Ethernet adapter to the wifi adapter,

check this,
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132674
it is so user friendly

Comment: The question was not about to have a bridge and the link you have given is named wrong. That was confusing me first because it isn't possible to bridge a wifi client connection. The author seems not to know what an ethernet bridge is. He described setting up routing. Anyway, that's usable for the problem.

Comment: You are now able to comment on every question. So you can make your "answer" a comment and delete it.

Comment: i think he want to transfer the traffic from the router to tv and vice versa, the pi is the middle man.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the RasPi a router that routes data between the wired and wireless interfaces. But I don't believe that the old RasPi with the limitations of USB for ethernet will be strong enough to ensure an uninterruptible video stream. You can try it. How to setup a router you can look at [Can a Raspberry Pi Zero W be turned into an USB WiFi dongle to any USB Host like x86 PC or mini-PC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98017/79866) but only use the section: **Use routing**.