# Use raspberry pi zero's wifi on my desktop

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I have a desktop that doesn't have any way of accessing the internet through WiFi at the moment. I can't get a USB WiFi network adapter or PCI-Express WiFi card any time soon but I have a raspberry pi zero W I bought a while back. Is there anyway I can use the raspberry pi's WiFi on the desktop by connecting it via USB?

Edit: also forgot to mention the desktop is running ubuntu

Comment: Connect it as an [*ethernet gadget*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ethernet+gadget%22) with the USB-OTG port and configure port forwarding to make the pi work as a sort of hotspot.

Comment: `make the pi work as a sort of hotspot` - wouldn't you want the pi wifi to be a "client" to the existing wifi network?

Comment: Duplicate of [Can a Raspberry Pi Zero W be turned into an USB WiFi dongle to any USB Host like x86 PC or mini-PC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97974/can-a-raspberry-pi-zero-w-be-turned-into-an-usb-wifi-dongle-to-any-usb-host-like)