# How do i make my raspberry pi zero w a wifi adapter

Tags: pi-zero-w

So my computer doesn't have wireless so i was wondering, is there a way my pi 0 W can share it's connection with my PC though USB

Comment: Not posting as an answer, but this might help [RPI Zero W AP Shared internet connection over WiFi?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=228940). It's badly written, but sounds like it's what you want to do... however, i have a feeling that the process doesn't quite match the title. The last link in that article seems to make the Pi Z an access point, which isn't what you are after. As cr1ptal states, just get a wifi USB dongle. It'll certainly be easier and probably more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to connect the Raspberry Pi Zero W to your PC with an USB cable and use [OTG Gadget ether emulation](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41) to get the USB connection emulated as an ethernet connection. Then you should have an interface **usb0** that you can use as an ethernet interface.

As you wrote you already have a WiFi uplink connection to your local internet router. So you must also have a WiFi interface, I assume its name is **wlan0**. Now you can use different solutions to transfer data between **usb0** and **wlan0**. For examples to do it, have a look at: [Can a Raspberry Pi Zero W be turned into an USB WiFi dongle to any USB Host like x86 PC or mini-PC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98017/79866).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no Wifi sharing on the Pi - it is a more advanced feature, simple computers don't have. A least not as standard Raspbian.
You can google if there is a software for Internet sharing over USB for the Pi, I doubt.

Moreover, it makes little sense to use a Pi for Internet-Wifi sharing. You will be better off with a Wifi device on your PC. If you want things to be simple, go for a USB dongle.

If you have a laptop, Wifi over USB it the best option.

If you have a Desktop, it could be interesting for you to learn how to plug a PCIe Wifi card into your motherboard.